# How to get template field/tab values in docusign API explorer

Tags: docusignapi

I created a sample template with field/tabs like first name, last name, DOB etc through app.docusign.com and I converted the template into Powerform and provided the values to the fields mentioned and finished the powerform. After that I am trying to retrieve those values using template and powerform API's in docusign API explorer.

When I try to retrieve those values I am getting an error "the template does not exists or you have no rights to it."

Actually the template is created and I have rights to it for my account Id. Anyone could you please help me on this how to get values from templates or powerform using docusign API explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of envelopes that were created from your DocuSign PowerForm with this- PowerFormData: list
https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=PowerForms&tags=PowerFormData&operations=list

It returns an array of envelopes, each with an array of recipients and each recipient with an array of formData that returns name value pairs for each tab on the envelope.